# How to update a vector list inside a node class?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

My func2 is not working properly it enters the func2 but then skips the whole comparison block from "if(line[i] == root->key) till the else statement and so in short my vector list inside the node class is not getting updated as well.
I need to search a record in bst against line that line I saved in the vector named line.

```
class Node {
public:
    string key;
    vector <string> l_num;
    Node *left, *right;
};

void func2(vector<string> line, Node* root, int i) {
if(root == NULL) {
    return;
}

if(line[i] == root->key) {
    root->l_num.push_back(line[i]);
    func2(line, root, i+1);
}
else if(line[i] < root->key) {
    func2(line, root->left, i);
}
else {
    func2(line, root->right, i);
}
}
```

Comment: But func2 is a global variable and it is getting all the public variables so why is it not working properly ?

Comment: If you want people to understand what `func2` is supposed to do - name it accordingly. `the_function_that_does_something`. I notice that you take the vector by value in `void func2(vector<string> line, Node* root, int i)`. Perhaps taking by reference would be a good idea?

Comment: Can you post full program, especially where the root is initialised?